# JQuery UI Accordion Not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I get an error in Opera Dragonfly that says "accordion is not a function" or something similar. Can someone please look at this code and tell me what I'm doing horribly wrong?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Accordion/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="Accordion/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="Accordion/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <link href="Accordion/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Accordion/jquery.ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#accordion').accordion();
        });
    </script>    
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">  
<div id="accordion">
    <h6>Section 1</h6>
    <div>
        <p>
        TEST 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <h6>Section 2</h6>
    <div >
        <p>
        TEST 2
        </p>
    </div>
    <h6>Section 3</h6>
    <div >
        <p>
        TEST 3
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Much appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Check your network tab. Is `jquery.ui.accordion.js` being loaded successfully?

Comment: It looks like it is loading up. How would I know if it isn't?

Comment: u can check it in Chrome Developer tools

Comment: Which language is it ? If not HTML5, add `type="text/javascript"`. Put that accordion call in `$(document).ready()`. There are minified versions of jQuery UI that contains everything. EDIT : Since you added no MIME-type, i assume it's HTML5. In that case content-less tags such as <link> are not supposed to be closed.

Comment: $(function () {}) works just fine as $(document).ready(). That's not the issue here. Much probably the UI library isn't being loaded.

Comment: Well i didn't even see it. Likely a reason not to use it. Saving a few octets at the price of a less intuitive code is maybe not a good idea.

Comment: yup I'm using HTML5 and yes I know there are minified versions but that wouldn't make a difference would it?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have a mistake on the scripts files paths?

Note the difference:

```
<!-- Starting with Scripts -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<!-- Starting with Accordion -->
<script src="Accordion/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="Accordion/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="Accordion/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did change them around and then tried again by dragging it in from the solution explorer, and manually typed them out. So unless I managed to do it wrong every time then it could be that but I doubt I did it wrong. I did also triple check so yeah...

Comment: If you're getting the message "... is not a function" the only possible reason is the library not being loaded. That's why I suspected it could be a wrong path. If you debug the page, let's say, with Firebug (Firefox), you can check if all the script files are being loaded.